# Spring batch job launching same job with incremented parameters

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I am looking to process a large tree, level by level. Job 1 would have parameter 1, job 2 would get parameter 2, etc ... Each job calling the next one while there is still a level to process.

I have a tasklet in which the data is processed, then inside I tried to launch the next job but I got an exception `existing transaction detected in jobrepository`.

Although not sure, I understood that launching a job from the execute function of another one is not a good idea.

I switched to adding a `JobExecutionListener` and launching the next level in the `afterJob()` method, allowing me to use the `ExecutionContext` to extract the params and send them incremented to the next job.

The problem I now face is the following;

1. `BatchConfig` declares the Job in a Configuration
2. The service that launches the first job imports the Job via a @Resource
3. The Listener is added within the `BatchConfig`
4. The Listener has to link to the service to be able to launch the job
5. How can I inject the service to launch the job inside the listener ? It is not a bean and passing it through the constructor results in a cyclic dependency.

I think I have the wrong design but I do not know how to do this properly.

Comment: Launching a Job from a Job is not a good idea.

Comment: Probably [JobStep](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.2.x/api/org/springframework/batch/core/step/job/JobStep.html) is what you are looking for, as it allows you to launch a job of jobs (though it would require a pre-analyse of the graph to know upfront how many (sub) jobs should be launched).

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine I looked into it and tried around, the steps work. The problem is now that when building the job, I don't know the tree depth (there are many trees in the database), how should I get this information since the job is created before the launch is called (and therefore I don't know on which tree) ?

Comment: That's what I said, this approach requires a pre-analysis of the tree to calculate the number of steps to launch upfront. Otherwise, I'm not sure Spring Batch would be a good fit for your use case (or at least the way you are intending to use it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nesting jobs will cause issues and make troubleshooting more difficult further down the lane.

Instead of launching a job from another one, what you can do is add a [`JobExecutionListener`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/api/org/springframework/batch/core/JobExecutionListener.html) on the job that is processing your levels.

Then in the `afterJob(JobExecution jobExecution)` callback, you can:

- Check the Job's `ExitStatus`
- Run the next Job

This requires some exit condition otherwise you will end up looping forever, and you will need to tell the next job to process the next level. These both can be achieved in several ways:

- Add an [`ExecutionContextPromotionListener`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/api/org/springframework/batch/core/listener/ExecutionContextPromotionListener.html) so you can pass parameters
- Directly in the Step's Tasklet by using the `ChunkContext`

Both solution will allow you to pass parameters via the `ExecutionContext`